# How to get debug information from a c++ application which is shipped to customer?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I am not sure if it is possible but assume that I have a c++ application and I am sendimng to our customers. The application may have bugs and hence it fails, but I can not get any information about the place that it failed. Is there any way that I can get debug information from such application?

I am using visual studio for development.

Comment: Logging, logging and even more logging.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg any library? any documentation or tutorial?

Comment: In addition, look into crash dumps, writing your own minidump using functions found in WinDbg.dll, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use a lot of logging:

- log start and end of every important action you are doing, of course
  make sure it doesn't effect application performance too much.
- log any errors from API calls or other failures from your routines.

And finally you can automatically generate crash dumps and allow user to submit this dump or lets say crash report including your application logs. This article will help you on how to catch you application crash and generate dump file: [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1934/Post-Mortem-Debugging-Your-Application-with-Minidu#_Writing_a_Minidump_with MiniDumpWri](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1934/Post-Mortem-Debugging-Your-Application-with-Minidu#_Writing_a_Minidump_with%20MiniDumpWri)